# CSS - positioning in % and px combine

Tags: css, positioning, fixed

Is there any way to set a div like that:

```
right: 50% - 450px;
```

I need it to be compatible for all resolutions.
It's a fixed div, and i need it to be in the center + 450px to the right.
anyone have a suggestion?

Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: right: calc(100% - 3em)

css3 calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used to this `Calc()`

`calc()` is a native CSS way to do simple math right in CSS as a replacement for any length value (or pretty much any number value). It has four simple math operators: add `(+)`, subtract `(-)`, multiply `(*)`, and divide `(/)`. Being able to do math in code is nice and a welcome addition to a language that is fairly number heavy.

```
right: calc(50% - 450px);
```

**[more info](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the `calc()` [function](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) like this:

CSS:

```
div {
     right: calc(50% - 450px);
}
```